# Client error: (405) Method Not Allowed while trying to use Neo4j syntax in R

Tags: r, neo4j, cypher, r-neo4j

I'm trying to use Neo4j in RStudio for the first time. I'm just trying this tutorial https://github.com/nicolewhite/RNeo4j

But when I try a query like this one:

```
nicole = createNode(graph, "Person", name="Nicole", age=24)
```

I got this error:

```
Client error: (405) Method Not Allowed
```

Is there any way to solve this problem? Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error can happen if you accidentally leave some information out of your `startGraph()` call.  Make sure you have `/db/data/` on the end of your graph's url.  (If this isnt the case then please post your `startGraph` command you used).

#### with `/db/data`

```
library(RNeo4j)
graph  = startGraph("http://localhost:7474/db/data/")
nicole = createNode(graph, "Person", name="Nicole", age=24)
nicole
# Person
# 
# $name
# [1] "Nicole"
# 
# $age
# [1] 24
```

#### without

```
graph  = startGraph("http://localhost:7474")
nicole = createNode(graph, "Person", name="Nicole", age=24)
Error: Client error: (405) Method Not Allowed
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply !! But unfortunately it's still not working for me
I used this:
 graph=startGraph("http://127.0.0.1:7474", username="username",password="password")
but when I use yours:
graph  = startGraph("http://localhost:7474/db/data/")
Error: Client error: (401) Unauthorized
Neo.ClientError.Security.Unauthorized
Invalid username or password.

Comment: And when I use it with username and password I got again this error:
Error: Client error: (401) Unauthorized
Neo.ClientError.Security.Unauthorized
Invalid username or password.

Comment: have you set a username & password?  i can only recreate that error by providing incorrect credentials.  if you are just going through examples it might be alright to just set `dbms.security.auth_enabled=false` in your `.neo4j.conf` and then you dont need user/pass